# Ruby on Rails Active Record Bank Database "unification"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have about three models which use bank account on all of them. I wish a intermediate table to solve to problem with references, but I'm not getting success:

### Models

- All models have => bank_name bank_number bank_agency bank_account
- Models => Clients People Offices

### Single Model Bank with references

What I want is create a single model Bank, with bank_name bank_number bank_agency bank_account that belongs to the other models (references), like this:

```rb
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :people
belongs_to :office
```

### Attempts

I've tried to create a single Model with Banks and them make a second table migration with references and also a Model with Banks with references already done, but the main problem is that rails make mandatory the three foreign_keys to work out, but I only only one of them in each bank account:

```rb
      t.references :person, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :client, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :office, null: false, foreign_key: true
```

Comment: You might want to look into [polymorphism](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) unless the bank account can really belong to all of those entities at once

Answer (score 0):

Use `null: true` to make the values optional.